# Separate Simple Signal into Exponential Components

Tags: analytic-signal

Everyone here should be familiar with the trignonometric identity

$$2 \cos(x)=e^{jx}+e^{-jx}$$

Let's say I have a real world analog signal given by the following function

$$x(t)=2\cos (\omega_1 t)$$

and I only want a single exponential component, specifically

$$y(t) = e^{j\omega_1 t}$$

where $\omega_1$ is a real constant. How to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: [I asked version 2 of this question with a $t^2$ term.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44491/separate-complicated-signal-into-exponential-components)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be finding the [analytic signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal) to a given real signal.

What you apparently need is the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform). This will allow you to "recreate" the imaginary part of $y(t)$ from the real part alone, which is essentially your measurement $x(t)$.

Note that the transform can only be approximated as it is a acausal filter, and only works best when the signal $x(t)$ is available in the computer for all $t$.

A simple implementation is to Fourier transform $x(t)$ and set the negative frequency components to zero. After transforming back you obtain (the complex signal) $y(t)$.

Comment: [This previous answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/43278/how-do-i-convert-a-real-baseband-signal-to-a-complex-baseband-signal/43281#43281) is also related and might be useful.